# How to repeat this function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, repeat

I have this function now in Excel VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = Cells(1, 5).Address Then
        Cells(1, 6) = Application.UserName
        Cells(1, 7) = Now
    Else
        Debug.Print "This was not B1"
    End If

End Sub
```

this works perfect for one cell on one line. Now I need to have it for multiple lines on this sheet. How do I do that? When just copying and updating the parameters in the Cells lines I get the error message that the eventname cannot be used twice.

Final solution for me would be that for all 15 lines on in this sheet I have this function.

Comment: `If Target.Address = Cells(1, 5).Address Then` look at OR so `If Target.Address = Cells(1, 5).Address or Target.Address = Cells(1, 5).Address Then`  or `intersect` for a range of cells maybe

Comment: Do you want to put in username and current date/time automatically in a specific range, when the user switches to that cell? It is difficult to visualize. Please break it down further.

Comment: @shahkalpesh Yes, I have fifteen lines with checks in Excel to be done by different users. When the user is done with his check I want the user to doubleclick the cell after their check so the username and date and time is added after the line. After some time when I open the file I want to see if everything has been done and when exactly. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `SelectionChange` event per worksheet, so you need to handle everything in that event.

If you want to do different things use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = Cells(1, 5).Address Then
        Cells(1, 6) = Application.UserName
        Cells(1, 7) = Now
    ElseIf Target.Address = … your other cell address … Then
        'do something else
    Else
        Debug.Print "This was not B1"
    End If

End Sub
```

---

If you want to do the same thing for multiple lines the do the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(Me.Cells(1, 5), Me.Cells(10, 5))) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1) = Application.UserName
        Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2) = Now
    Else
        Debug.Print "This was not B1"
    End If

End Sub
```

This will work from row 1 `Me.Cells(1, 5)` to row 10 `Me.Cells(10, 5)` and will write the username to column 6 and time to column 7 of the selected row of column 5 in that range.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick indeed. Additional one: is it possible to change the trigger from selecting the cell to doubleclicking the cell?